# The Node.js native addon module (tfjs_binding.node) can not be found

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am trying to use the '@tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu' package. I used the require function to create an instance of the package `const tf = require("@tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu");`

After I ran this, it gave me this error:

```
Error: The Node.js native addon module (tfjs_binding.node) can not be found at path: node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node-gpu\lib\napi-v6\tfjs_binding.node.
Please run command 'npm rebuild @tensorflow/tfjs-node build-addon-from-source' to rebuild the native addon module.

If you have a problem with building the addon module, please check https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/blob/master/tfjs-node/WINDOWS_TROUBLESHOOTING.md or file an issue at Object.<anonymous>
```

**I have manually shortened the paths to keep things tidy here**

Also, `const tf = require("@tensoreflow/tfjs-node");` works without errors

I have tried running `npm rebuild @tensorflow/tfjs-node build-addon-from-source` & `npm rebuild @tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu build-addon-from-source` It did not work. I also tried reinstalling the packages, which did not work. Anything else I can try?

Also I am running Windows.